# How could I reset a level up progress bar when I level up discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How could I reset a level up progress bar when I level up discord.js. What I mean is the bar resets but displays how much xp you need to get.

For example.

Level 1 Person should see
50/60 (means 10 xp to go)
Level 1 now level to person sees
60/120 (means 60 60 xp to go)

I want it to be 50/60
and then 0/120

How could I do this

Thanks for any help.

````
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rank')
        .setDescription('Get a members rank')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('Provide a valid user to see the level/rank').setRequired(false)),
    async execute (interaction) {
        const { options, user, guild } = interaction;

        const Member = options.getMember('user') || user;

        const member = guild.members.cache.get(Member.id);

        const Data = await levelSchema.findOne({ Guild: guild.id, User: member.id});

        if (!Data) return await interaction.reply({ content: `${member} has not gained any XP yet.`, ephemeral: true})

        await interaction.deferReply()

        const Required = Data.Level * Data.Level * 100 + 100;

        const rank = new Canvacord.Rank()
            .setAvatar(member.displayAvatarURL({ forseStatic: true}))
            .setBackground("IMAGE", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1106871953995862047/1106871982760411187/witchshiftingstatic.png")
            .setCurrentXP(Data.XP)
            .setRequiredXP(Required)
            .setRank(1, "Rank", false)
            .setLevel(Data.Level, "Level")
            .setUsername(member.user.username)

            const Card = await rank.build()
            const rankAttachment = new AttachmentBuilder(Card, { name: "rank.png" });

        const rankEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("023020")
            .setTitle(`${member.user.username}'s Level`)
            .setImage("attachment://rank.png")

        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [rankEmbed], files: [rankAttachment]})
    }
}```

Sorry if this is
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your experience scale is in powers of 2 multiplying 60, (i.e. level 0 is 60, level 1 is 120, level 2 is 240, etc), your required experience can be described as such:

[image: Required experience function]

In your code, in whatever function is used to level up:

```js
const Required = 60*Math.pow(2,Data.Level)
```

then set the players current XP to 0.

**Note:** I notice you calculate the required experience every time the rank command is invoked. You should like to pre-calculate the level and store it in whatever database you use to call the data, rather than calculate it every time, to remain consistent with the rest of your data.